# How can I fill a 2d array, with random caracters? Using classes in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

Im doing a Word Search Puzzle puzzle for school and the problem im facing is the following.

I am trying to fill a 2d array with random caracters, which is not hard, but when you introduce classes and pointers.. It get confusing. So I have a class called Char, and its function is to generate the random char to store inside the 2d array present in the class Board.

```
class Char
{
private:

    char Letters;

public:

    Char();
    Char(char let);
    ~Char();

    void Set_Letters(char let) { Letters = let; }
    char Get_Letters(void) { return Letters; }

    void Random(void);
    void View(void);
};

class Board
{

private:

    int BoardWidth;
    int BoardHeight;
    int numWords;
    Char** Caracters;

    Point P; //This is ponting to an other class called Point, it keeps track of the location of the Words that were read from the txt file
public:

    Board(void);
    ~Board();

    void Init(int Dx, int Dy);

    inline void Set_BoardWidth(int bW) { BoardWidth = bW; }
    inline void Set_Boardheight(int bH) { BoardHeight = bH; }
};
```

So those are the important classes. In the class Board the variable that I am using to store the 2d array is the Char**, which I dont even know if that is the correct way to do it.
These are the relevant code behind the functions in the class Char:

```
void Char::Random()
{

    //The unsigned int is used to silence the error : "Possible loss of data"
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    Set_Letters('A' + (rand() % 26));
}
```

This creates the random char´s, and this is the part that is supposed to save the char´s in the 2d array.

```
void Board::Init(int Dx, int Dy)
{

    Set_BoardWidth(Dx);
    Set_Boardheight(Dy);

    Char Letter;
    int n = 0, m = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < Dy; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Dx; i++)
        {
            //Fill the array with random char´s
            Letter.Random();
            **Caracters = Letter.Get_Letters();
            //In this part im attributing a x and y value to the char
            P.Set_x(n); P.Set_y(m);
            n++; m++;
        }
    }
}
```

The error that it gives me is:

> "Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   `this->Caracters was nullptr`".

I tried to create a string in the Board class to store it all, but it didn´t seem to work, for some reason the class wouldn´t even recognize the variable when I used it. Also tried to use `char**`, gave me the same error.

And that´s about it, haven't tried anything else. After watching a video it gave me the idea of using a vector, but I haven´t tried it yet.

I just finished learning C in the past semester and I feel like I'm still too much grabbed in to it. And im having a hard time to sepperate them both. So if you have any tip on how I could be better and what I can improve also im my way of writing code please let me know.

Comment: You never allocated any memory in your code. Why are you even using pointers and manual dynamic memory allocation in the first place?

Comment: I'm not surprised you're confused, a class to generate random characters is massive overkill. Just write a function to do that. Not everything has to be done with classes. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: I don´t know, somehow I thought it might work?

Comment: The thing is we have a protocol to follow, and I need that class. At least the teacher says that it as to be there. Most likely I will have to take that path if I can´t solve this

Answer (score 0):

I've created some sample code to show one way this could be done using more modern C++ libraries. `rand()` is not recommended since it's just not very good at its job, and using modulo arithmetic to force a range also skews results.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

class Board {
 public:
  explicit Board(int rows, int columns)
      : m_rows(rows), m_columns(columns), m_board(rows * columns, '0') {
    for (auto& i : m_board) {
      i = capital(prng);
    }
  }
  void print() const {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < m_columns; ++j) {
        std::cout << m_board[i * m_columns + j] << ' ';
      }
      std::cout << '\n';
    }
  }

 private:
  int m_rows = 0;
  int m_columns = 0;
  std::vector<char> m_board = {};

  static std::random_device rd;
  static std::mt19937 prng;
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<char> capital;
};

std::random_device Board::rd;
std::mt19937 Board::prng(Board::rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<char> Board::capital('A', 'Z');

int main() {
  Board board(5, 5);
  board.print();
}
```

I got rid of the character class; it wasn't necessary. Instead of an array, we'll use a vector. They're generally better to use, overall. Note that it's 1D. This performs better than a vector of vectors. Our `Board` class will just use some arithmetic tricks to pretend that it's 2D. You can see how that works in the print function.

I included the random number generator tools in the class as static members. That was another problem with your code; you were re-seeding every time you called the `Random()` function. You only seed once. `static` in C++ classes means that all objects of that type share the static members.

`static` members have to be initialized outside of the class unless they are `inline static` and you are compiling with C++17 or higher. I let the constructor fill the board with random letters. This is the C++ way of doing things when possible. Your `Init()` function was just poorly doing the job of the constructor.

Furthermore, I am no longer managing dynamic resources on my own. There's a lot more that needs to go into this class like an iterator and maybe `operator[]`, but the code shown solves your current problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use what you have taught me to the best of my capabilities. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it. You´ve helped a lot.